# SVN Merge just revision changes only

Tags: xcode, svn, version-control, svn-merge, revisions

Assume I have Revision 101, Revision 102, and Revision 103 for Folder A.
I would like to merge Folder A to Folder B with only the changes that where committed in Revision 103 for folder A. I do not want the changes in revision 102.
My understanding is that Merging Revision 103 will merge everything including 102 and 101. How can I just merge to Folder B just the changes in revision 103?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [cherrypicking](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.branchmerge.advanced.html#svn.branchmerge.cherrypicking):

> Just as the term “changeset” is often used in version control systems,
>   so is the term cherrypicking. This word refers to the act of choosing
>   one specific changeset from a branch and replicating it to another.

```
svn merge -c 103 path_to_repo
```